# Boost Spitirt - Single Struct, Multiple Rules

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Given the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html) in the boost docs how can I write another rule for the same struct?

For example, suppose I wanted the parser to also accept a rule like:

```
start2 %=
        lit("employee2")
        >> '['
        >>  double_ >> ','
        >>  quoted_string >> ','
        >>  quoted_string >> ','
        >>  int_
        >>  ']'
        ;
```

So that the input would accept data in the format

```
employee { int, "string", "string", double}
```

OR

```
employee2 [ double, "string", "string", int")
```

While using the same struct as provided in the example. Is this possible without having to use another "adapter" struct? If so, how?

Comment: what happened to the answer of this question?