# Boost Spirit - Parser Capturing Unwanted Text

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I have a simple struct

```
// in namespace client
struct UnaryExpression
{
    std::string key;
    SomeEnums::CompareType op;
};
```

`SomeEnums::CompareType` is an enum where I define a symbol table as such:

```
struct UnaryOps : bsq::symbols<char, SomeEnums::CompareType>
{
    UnaryOps() : bsq::symbols<char, SomeEnums::CompareType>(std::string("UnaryOps"))
    {
        add("exists", SomeEnums::Exists)
          ("nexists", SomeEnums::NotExists);
    }
};
```

I have two different ways I want to parse the struct, which I asked about in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514983/boost-spitirt-single-struct-multiple-rules) and got to work (mostly).

My grammar looks as follows:

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct test_parser : bsq::grammar<Iterator, client::UnaryExpression(), bsq::ascii::space_type>
{
    test_parser()
        : test_parser::base_type(unaryExp, std::string("Test"))
    {
        using bsq::no_case;

        key %= bsq::lexeme[bsq::alnum >> +(bsq::alnum | bsq::char_('.'))];

        unaryExp %= unaryE | unaryF;
        unaryE %= key >> no_case[unaryOps];
        unaryF %= no_case[unaryOps] >> '(' >> key >> ')';
    };

    UnaryOps unaryOps;

    bsq::rule<Iterator, std::string(), bsq::ascii::space_type> key;
    bsq::rule<Iterator, client::UnaryExpression(), bsq::ascii::space_type> unaryExp;
    bsq::rule<Iterator, client::UnaryExpression(), bsq::ascii::space_type> unaryE;
    bsq::rule<Iterator, client::UnaryFunction(), bsq::ascii::space_type> unaryF;
};
```

And I'm parsing the code using the following logic:

```
bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, parser, bsq::ascii::space, exp);

if (r && iter == end)
{
    std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
    std::cout << "key: " << exp.key << "\n";
    std::cout << "op : " << exp.op << "\n";
    std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
}
```

This all works fine if I do the input like `foo exists` and exp.key equals "foo" and exp.op equals the corresponding enum value (in this case 0). Something like `foo1 nexists` also works.

However, that second rule doesn't work like I expect. If I give it input of `nexists(foo)` then I get the following output:

```
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
key: nexistsfoo
op : 1
-------------------------
```

It seems that the enum value is getting set appropriately but I can't figure out why the "nexsts" is getting prepended to the key string. Can someone please tell me how I can fix my rule so that the key would equal just 'foo' with the second rule?

I have posted a copy of the stripped down code that illustrates my problem here: http://pastebin.com/402M9iTS

Comment: I'm not sure why but changing `unaryExp %= unaryE | unaryF;` to `unaryExp %= unaryF | unaryE;` solved the problem

Comment: You can find an explanation to the same problem here. Your solution is better (and with a cleaner grammar) since it doesn't need to keep temporary copies but another alternative is using [qi::hold](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/hold.h‌​tml). Your rule would then be: `unaryExp %= bsq::hold[unaryE] | unaryF;`.

Comment: @llonesmiz Did you intend to post a link with that?

Comment: @sehe Yeah, [this one](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.parsers.spirit.general/20429). I recreated the comment to add something once the time for editing had passed and it was lost in the copy-paste. The link to `qi::hold` is also busted. [This](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/hold.html) is the correct one.